# Azure VPN private IP redundancy

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

The company has taken over many branches in different regions of the world. The problem is we are moving to Azure and these new branch's network/subnet private IP address is same. How can we make a VPN connection to share the connection with other branches?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [VPN Gateway NAT](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/vpn-nat-now-ga/) that just went GA a few days ago. Azure VPN NAT (Network Address Translation) supports overlapping address spaces between your on-premises branch networks and your Azure Virtual Networks. You can go through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/nat-overview) for additional details.